# dapper-extensions GetList() with (nolock)

Tags: sql-server, dapper, dapper-extensions, nolock

Does anyone know if it's possible to tell dapper to append `with (nolock)` when using `connection.GetList<TView>()`?

I am using this as the R from my CQRS model and it works well but I'm concerned now we're doing a bit more heavy reading that it will start locking out tables.  I'd rather not add transactions into the mix if possible.

Comment: Which package of CQRS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) is really just a set of extension methods plunked on top of [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview). It's meant to be a **generic** abstraction allowing it to interop with (m)any RDMS's.

Since `with (nolock)` is [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table) syntax, it wouldn't make a ton of sense for it to be baked into any of the methods, extension lib or otherwise.

Moreover, the [dapper-extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) package is meant to help with the simple task of CRUD operations. If the complexity goes beyond these operations, it's time for `.Query()` and some custom SQL.